# Using a 'for' loop iterator after the loop exits in C

Tags: c, for-loop, c99

For years, I've gotten in to the habit of not using the value of a `for` loop iterator after the loop exits. I could have sworn that I did this, because it used to produce a compiler warning, but after I was challenged in a recent code review, I was proven wrong.

For example, I always did this (NOTE: our code standards prohibit the use of the "break" keyword):

```
int i, result;
bool done = false;
for (i=0; i<10 && !done; i++) {
    if (some_condition) {
        result = i;
        done = true;
    }
}
// Value of i may be undefined here
```

Now, obviously the `result` variable could be removed, if I can rely on the value of i. I thought that because of compiler optimization, you could not rely on the value of the loop iterator. Am I just remembering a phantom teaching? Or is this the standard (specifically regarding GNU C)?

Comment: *"(NOTE: our code standards prohibit the use of the "break" keyword):"* - Excuse me, but WTF?

Comment: If I remember right the minute you introduce a second variable into the iterator limit then most of the optimisations the C99 can give you go out the window. Its then no better than a while loop with an i++; at the end.

Comment: 'break;' is basically the same as a 'goto', which is evil.  Besides, I don't make the rules, and anyone who works in a place with no code standards should fine a new place to work.

Comment: 'break;' is very different to 'goto'; it is localised / construct scope specific. Shit standards are shit standards.

Comment: "goto" is considered evil because it flaunts flow control completely. "break" on the other hand is a specific flow control, usable in only a handle of places for a specific purpose - to break out of a loop.

Comment: Surely anyone who works in a place with no code standards should just get on and write some?

Comment: Anyone who works in a place that has code standards and goes "WTF" at them on a regular basis should consider re-writing them. Bad standards lead to bad/unmaintainable code. Good code standards are unfortunately few and far between

Comment: Both `goto` and `break` are good if used correctly. Personally I think it's hard to find an example of a "bad" `goto` without having at least 3 labels in the function and `goto` statements interspersed with labels (i.e. situations where all the `goto` statements are at the top and all the labels are at the bottom are almost never problematic).

Comment: Any "optimization" which causes the value of `i` to be undefined there is broken.

Comment: @Michael, MISRA-C:2012 has no such rule, and in fact has some precautionary guidance of their usage in loops, but does not ban them.

Comment: @Veriloud: yes - I see that the rule was rescinded in MISRA C 2004.  I'm going to delete the comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in [C89](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89), [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) to access the iteration variable after the `for` statement.

```
 int i;

 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     /* Some code */
 }

 printf("%d\n", i);  // No magic, the value is 10
```

From C99, you can use also a declaration as the first clause of the `for` statement, and in that case of course the declared variable cannot be used after the `for` statement.

Comment: Do you mean to use `i` rather than `10` in your `printf`?

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  I'm not sure how this habit entered my code style, and I stand corrected.  In C there is nothing wrong with using the (properly scoped) for loop iterator after the loop is complete.

Comment: Unless /* some code */ is replaced by break; In that case, the variable i would contain the value 0 (i++ is not executed after break).

Comment: While it's possible, doesn't mean it's good practice. If you're using i after the loop, it's likely not for the purpose of iterating. Simply create another variable for the purpose after the for loop, initialized within the for loop. Makes for better readability (beyond the for loop) and future maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

Different languages have different rules.  In Pascal, the compiler is allowed to optimize away storing the loop index after the final increment, so it *might* be the first loop-terminating value or it *might* be the last valid value.

Comment: I think you got it here.  Pascal was the first language I was actually taught, a million years ago back in AP Computer Porgraming in 1995.  I think this is where this habit was drilled into me, and it carried over into C.  Interesting...

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of usage cases where the for loop is used for nothing else *but* advancing the iterator. This can be seen in some implementations of strlen (though admittedly there are other ways to do strlen), and other sorts of functions whose goal it is to find a certain limit:

```
/*find the index of the first element which is odd*/
for (ii = 0; ii < nelem && arry[ii] % 2 == 0; ii++);
```

As mentioned, the point of confusion may come from constructs where the iterator itself is defined within the for statement.

In general for statements are very very powerful, and it's unfortunate that they're usually never utilized to their full potential.

For example, a different version of the same loop can be written as follows (though it wouldn't demonstrate the safety of using the iterator):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int cur, ii = 0, nelem, arry [] = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 3, 42, 45, 67 };
    int sum = 0;

    nelem = sizeof(arry) / sizeof(int);
    /* Look mom! no curly braces! */

    for (
            ii = 0;
            ii < nelem && ((cur = arry[ii]) %2 == 0 ||
                                ((printf("Found odd number: %d\n", cur)||1)));
            ii++, sum += cur
        );
    printf("Sum of all numbers is %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

In this particular case, it seems like a lot of work for this specific problem, but it can be very handy for some things.

Comment: Very smooth.  I love it.  Unfortunately it wouldn't pass code review at my work :(

Answer (score 0):

Even though the value of that `for` loop's control variable is well defined, you might have been told to avoid using the `for` loop's control variable after the for loop because of the way scoping of that variable is handled, and especially because the handling has changed of the history of C++ (I know this question is tagged "C", but I think the rationale for avoiding using for loop control variable after the loop may have origins in this C++ history).

For example, consider the following code:

```
int more_work_to_do(void) 
{
    return 1;
}

int some_condition(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int foo()
{
    int i = 100;

    while (more_work_to_do()) {
        int done = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !done; i++) {
            if (some_condition()) {
                done = 1;
            }
        }

        if (done) return i;   // which `i`?
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Under some old rules of scoping for the `i` declared in the `for` loop, the value returned on the statement marked with the comment "which `i`" would be determined by the `for` loop (VC++ 6 uses these rules).  Under the newer, standard rules for scoping that variable, the value returned will be the `i` declared at the start of the function.

Comment: Indeed, the reason this practice is avoided is purely due to C++ - both this historic incompatibility, and a general C++ philosophy that the iterator should be local to the loop. IMO there is no good reason to avoid it in C, which is a completely different language

Comment: Even if you consider only C99 standard behavior here, there may still be reasons to avoid redeclaring `i` in difference scopes, for example to help prevent introducing errors during maintenance. See Eric Lippert's article explaining a rationale for C# making many redeclarations of local variables outright errors: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx  I know it's yet again a different language, but the language designers drew on a history of bugs that suggested it was a problem area.

Comment: When I said "avoid it", I meant avoiding using `i` after the loop. I see no reason to avoid doing that in C. Personally I would always avoid scoping `i` in the loop, since I tend to like using its value after the loop terminates, and for the reason you said (the risk of shadowing another variable), even though GCC is good at warning about the latter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will generate a compiler warning in both C and C++, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @David: you're right that GCC and MSVC will issue a warning when compiling the above as C++.  GCC does not issue a warning when compiling it as C99 code (MSVC won't compile it as C code because MSVC doesn't support declaration of variables in a `for` loop when compiling C).

Answer (score 0):

While I can't possibly know how your habit came to be, I can tell you how my habit to do the same did. It was by seeing code like this:

```
for (i=0u; (i<someLimit) && (found != TRUE); i++)
{
    if (someCondition) found = TRUE;
}
foundIndex = i-1;
```

Basically, code like this is written when the break keyword is disallowed by some coding rules, e.g. based on MISRA. If you don't break out of the loop though, the loop will usually leave you with an "i" which is off by one from what you care for.

Sometimes, you can even find this:

```
for (i=0u; (i<someLimit) && (found != TRUE); i++)
{
    if (someCondition) found = TRUE;
}
foundIndex = i;
```

This is just semantically wrong and can be found when the "forbid break keyword rule" is introduced into an existing code base which is not sufficiently covered by unit tests. May sound surprising, but it's all out there...

Comment: The last two versions of MISRA-C:2004 & MISRA-C:2012 has no such rules against break, in fact has some precautionary guidance of their usage in loops, but does not ban them.

Comment: It definitely has rules about putting {} around the "found = TRUE", though. And surely it has rules about not doing "found != TRUE" -- just say "! Found", because there is no unique true in C. It's ok here, IF found was initialised to 0 (or specifically TRUE) before the  because of the assignment of TRUE in the loop, but the initialisation is not shown; if it was the result of some other integer expression the loop may not be skipped as the programmer might expect. Anyway it's a bad habit.